# How would conditional precedence work in php? Eg: (A && B || C)

Tags: php

Lets say you have a condition like this-

```
if($i || $j && $k)
```

or this-

```
if($i && $j || $k)
```

How would the precedence work in these cases among && and ||

Edit: the conditionals are also evaluated as other operators and their precedence can be seen here-
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Just check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php ...

Comment: @Rizier123 he both asked and answered the question in the same min...

Comment: Thanks for the link @Rizier123! I couldn't remember the term operator precedence. Hence the question!
@MartinBarker I wanted to have it in the SO just in case..

Comment: @MartinBarker I know that he self-answered his question, but still the question as it is, is answered by just looking into the manual, which takes just one or two minutes.

Comment: @Rahul Just putting the keywords into google yields that: `PHP precedence` or just `PHP 
How would the precedence work in these cases among && and ||` first or second link is the manual.

Comment: @Rizier123 as I said, the word `precedence` eluded me. I was instead googling _php Which will be evaluated first && or ||_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($i || $j && $k)
```

is like

```
if($i || ($j && $k))
```

---

```
if($i && $j || $k)
```

is

```
if(($i && $j) || $k)
```

Try them for yourself and see !

---

Look at the complete list of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

```
associativity      operators
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
non-associative    clone new
left               [
right              **
right              ++ -- ~ (int) (float) (string) (array) (object) (bool) @
non-associative    instanceof
right              !
left               * / %
left               + - .
left               << >>
non-associative    < <= > >=
non-associative    == != === !== <> <=>
left               &
left               ^
left               |
left               &&
left               ||
right              ??
left               ? :
right              = += -= *= **= /= .= %= &= |= ^= <<= >>= =>
left               and
left               xor
left               or
left               ,
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've found is that php will execute the *and conditional* first, then it will check the *or conditional*. Eg-

```
if($i || ($j && $k))
```

or

```
if(($i && $j) || $k)
```

I wrote a small code to get the answer-

```
<?php

foreach(array(0,1) as $i){
    foreach(array(0,1) as $j){
        foreach(array(0,1) as $k){
            echo "\n$i\t$j\t$k";
            if($i || $j && $k){
                echo "\nya";
            } else {
                echo "\nna";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

and the answer was-

```
0   0   0
na
0   0   1
na
0   1   0
na
0   1   1
ya
1   0   0
ya
1   0   1
ya
1   1   0
ya
1   1   1
```